# How to specify that redirect link uses post method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a view I have links with the following format:

```
<%= link_to "User", move_on_path(organization: organization, url: edit_profile_path(@user)) %>
```

This uses a controller method that first calls on a method that sets a `session` value and then moves on to the specified `url`:

```
def move_on
  @organization = Organization.find_by(params[:organization])
  set_session(@organization)
  redirect_to params[:url]
end
```

This works but now I have an `url` for which the method is `post` rather then `get`. I don't know the syntax for the link when it's a `post` method. So I have the syntax below but need it to `post` to `edit_profile_path`. How can I specify this in the syntax below (or is there no way around changing `def move_on` for this)?

```
<%= link_to "User", move_on_path(organization: organization, url: edit_profile_path(@user)) %>
```

**Update:** Using @Chuck Callebs answer below I've changed the controller method to:

```
def move_on
  @organization = Organization.find_by(params[:organization])
  set_session(@organization)
  if params[:_url] == 'users#edit'
    post_to params[:url]
  else
    redirect_to params[:url]
end
```

Would this be correct? I made up `post_to` to explain what I would like it to do, but what would be the correct code as to make it post to the `url`?

**I don't think it's a duplicate post since it's more about looking for the solution in this use case then about whether a `post` request is possible.**

Comment: Why are you using POST in the first place?

Comment: For the above example of editing a user profile it indeed makes no sense, but I also have links for for example removing a role the user has in an organization. Thats where I use post requests.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's a way to use a redirect_to with a POST.

This is because redirect_to simply sends a HTTP 30x redirect header to the browser. The browser then initiates a GET request on the target URL. You have 2 options as I see them:

- Make a new controller method for this particular redirect (a GET request, which would perform a similar task)
- You can utilize `request.get?` method in your existing controller method to handle any discrepancies between the two requests.

**Update**

I think you should wrap the functionality in the POST request into a service object and just call it directly in the `move_on` method. That's the route I'd go. That being said, if you need to do the above approach, see this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10614765/14877

If you end up going that route, you should write a helper method (maybe even call it `post_to` :)) that would handle the details for you.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, I've added an update to the original post with what I think you suggest. Could you perhaps have a look at it?

Comment: @Nick Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

following the `link_to` documentation http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

I think all you need is to add the `method` option:

```
<%= link_to "User", move_on_path(organization: organization, url: edit_profile_path(organization.id), method: :post) %>
```

Comment: This would cause the original click to be sent to move_on_path via a POST request, I believe what the OP is requesting is that the redirect is sent via POST which as Chuck pointed out is not possible.

Comment: you're right @TomWalpole. Now I understand what he needs...