# Is there a way to stop a setInterval without its timerId?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

Just wondering if it is possible to stop the timer (from browser's console) which is set by `setInterval` without its timer id and without using browser extensions?

I know that there is no straighforward way possible (without timer id) as per documentation, but are there any workarounds possible?

Comment: Related [Viewing all the timouts/intervals in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858619/viewing-all-the-timouts-intervals-in-javascript)

Comment: I really liked the challenge so I posted [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35937155/1449624) in the duplicate.